# Filtering or checking triple quoted JSON objects in Kibana/Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've been trying to filter on a **non indexed** nested JSON field, and taking into account the following sample document (retrieved using Kibana Dev Tools).

```
{
    "id": "",
    "timestamp": "",
    "innerData": {
        "innerField": "",
        "innerJson": """{ inner json in here }"""
    }
}
```

I've got several questions since I've been trying to filter keys within `innerJson` (not indexed) without any success.

Is it triple quoted in Kibana for sake of readability since being a JSON it contains several quotes? Is it possible to filter values for the `innerData.innerJson` map the same you would do for current document fields such as `innerData.innerField`?

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "innerData.innerJson.INNER_JSON_FIELD": {
          "value": "*sample*"
       }
    }
}
}
```

I've been playing around with ES for a bit and taking a big index into account (100M entries approximate) I assume that by doing such filter in a **non** indexed field this would be an expensive operation? Any recommended optimization to not hit the performance too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON itself does not support triple quotes so yes, it's a Kibana readability convention. When you inspect the proxied requests, you can see that all double quotes inside of double quotes get escaped --> `" \"...\" "`.

As to the field `innerJson` -- since it's not indexed, it's not searchable so there's really no way to filter on it, let alone access the stringified's JSON inner properties. Leaving is as `text` and wildcarding on it is *very* expensive but it would be possible *if* it were `indexed`.

How many key-value pairs does the inner JSON have? What prevents you from parsing it before ingesting into ES?