# Elasticsearch puts multiple quotes around a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to store json in elastic index.

Data in topic which is written to elasticsearch index looks like this:
`"["banana"]"`

When data enters the index it looks like this:
`"""["banana"]"""`

Mapping for this field looks like this:

```
"bananaField": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't have an array. It has a string that contains brackets and quotes

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093136/4604579

Comment: @OneCricketeer So how do I fix the problem so the value in the index contains only one outer quote? Also, why does elastic put the extra quotes around the string?

Comment: @Val I am not sure how this helps me

Comment: Also, when i fetch this value from code, how many quotes will it contain, if any?

Comment: You mentioned the data comes from somewhere else? Kafka? Show us that code. Elasticsearch isn't the problem, and you shouldn't force it to parse what you think should be JSON, when it is only a string